# Zend Route overwrites all the urls exist in current page

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I am using Zend Router in my project and the rule is like this;

```
<projects type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex">
            <route>project/(\d+)/(.+)</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>project</controller>
                <action>view</action>
            </defaults>
            <map>
                <projectid>1</projectid>
            </map>
            <reverse>project/%d/%s</reverse>
        </projects>
```

When i go below url;

```
http://mydomain/project/1/project_name
```

All the urls exist on this page are replaced with above url.For example, there is a link in this page for sending message to project owner.When i hover on that link, i see that url is as defined above.Message sending url is created like this;

```
<a href="<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/misc/sendmessage">Send Message</a>
```

As you can see above, i am using url helper and the content of baseUrl is simply gets keyword called "baseUrl" from appliation.ini file.

Have you ever faced a problem like this?

Thanks in advance

KR
Hüseyin

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of how you are creating one of the links on the page that is incorrect. I'm guessing you're using the URL helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "`<route>default</route>`" to all pages in navigation.This default route must be added to navigation xml for each page.The problem is fixed

Current navigation.xml:

```
......
<settings>
   <label>Settings</label>
   <title>Settings</title>
   <resource>edit</resource>
   <privilege>edit</privilege>
   <controller>experts</controller>
   <action>edit</action>
</settings>
......
```

Updated navigation xml:

```
......
<settings>
   <label>Settings</label>
   <title>Settings</title>
   <resource>edit</resource>
   <privilege>edit</privilege>
   <controller>experts</controller>
   <action>edit</action>
   <route>default</route>
</settings>
......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand your problem

How do you set the baseUrl value in your applicaiton.ini file? It should be like this:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "baseUrl"
```

And using base url view helper does not seem to be the best choice for your case. Why don't you use url view helper?

```
url($urlOptions, $name, $reset);
```

Comment: the aim of url helpe that i used above is only get base url of the project.